# Неизвестная переменная при обновление поля в БД

Tags: php, html, sql, формы

Всем привет. Такая ситуация, решил сделать для сайта раздел с обновлением профиля. Но столкнулся с такими ошибками при отправление формы:

> Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\profileedit.php on line 9
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\profileedit.php:9) in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\profileedit.php on line 26

Код страницы:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Логин</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="Bek1zo<?php //echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>" disabled>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-Mail</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email'] ?>"">
    </div>
</div>
```

Имя
      
          ">

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Фамилия</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="surname" placeholder="Укажите вашу фамилию" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['surname'] ?>">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Страна проживания</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country" placeholder="Введите страну, где вы проживаете в данный момент" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['country'] ?>">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Город проживания</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="Введите город где вы находитесь" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['city'] ?>">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Дата рождения</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="age" placeholder="Укажите дату вашего рождения" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['age'] ?>">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Пароль</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Введите пароль" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="updateprofile">Обновить информацию</button>
        <a href="/index.php"><button class="btn btn-default">Вернуться в профиль</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Код PHP:

```
<?php

require_once 'core/config.php';

if (isset($_POST['updateprofile'])) {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $surname = $_POST['surname'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $country = $_POST['country'];
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $age = $_POST['age'];

        $db->execute("
            update `users` set 
            `email`='$email',`name`='$name',`surname`='$surname',`password`='$password',`country`='$country',`city`='$city',`age`='$age' 
            where `username`='$username'
        ");

    header('Location: /admin.php');
}

$pageTemplate = 'profileedit';

include 'web/main.phtml';   // подключение основной страницы

?>
```

Comment: что выводит `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: Обновил выше коммент. Сглупил и забыл ";" поставить после vardump'a

Comment: Поиск в гугле headers already sent . Даже сайт кто-то сделал, посвящённый этой ошибке http://cannot-modify-header-information.ru/ . Прежде чем программировать, надо учиться пользоваться поиском.

Comment: Основной вопрос был в переменной. А headers already send уже поправил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="Bek1zo<?php //echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>" disabled>`

jQuery не отправляет поля формы с атрибутом `disabled`. Поэтому, в массиве `$_POST` у вас нет элемента `$_POST['username']`

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, все заработало :) Как раз туда и стал щас смотреть.